# Not calling dealloc on UIViewController in Xamarin

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a `UIViewController` written in a native library that is bound to my Xamarin app. The controller has a method as follows:

```
+ (instancetype)newInstance
{
    return [SharedData.sharedInstance.mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"worksheetController"];
}
```

This method is bound to my Xamarin app as follows:

```
// @interface WorksheetTableViewController : UIViewController
[BaseType(typeof(UIViewController))]
interface WorksheetTableViewController
{
    // +(instancetype)newInstance;
    [Static]
    [Export("newInstance")]
    WorksheetTableViewController NewInstance();
}
```

Now in my Xamarin app in a `UIViewController` subclass in ViewDidLoad I call the method as follows:

```
this.worksheetController = WorksheetTableViewController.NewInstance();
```

The `worksheetController` is not used anywhere else in the `UIViewController`. When this `UIViewController` is disposed (by popping off the navigation stack), the `dealloc` method of `WorksheetTableViewController` is not called.

However if I change my code in ViewDidLoad to be as follows:

```
this.worksheetController = (WorksheetTableViewController)SharedData.SharedInstance.MainStoryboard.InstantiateViewController("worksheetController");
```

when the `UIViewController` is disposed, the dealloc method gets called.

To me there doesn't seem to be any difference in the `newInstance` method in the native code and directly calling `InstantiateViewController` in Xamarin. Yet in the former case `dealloc` is not being called, while everything is fine in the later.

Can someone explain why the memory management is different in the two cases?

Comment: It's just guess, but try rename method `newInstance` at something else without `new` and `create`.  There is exist convention that objects returned from `new`, `copy` and `create` methods are owned (taking side is responsible for their releasing). It's now doesn't matter in ARC, but who knows how it works in xamarin, may be it add extra `retain` for such methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because ARC will implicitly retain the return value from the native `newInstance` method [1], and Xamarin.iOS will not implicitly detect that.

You have two options:

1. Rename the native method to something that doesn't start with `new` or `copy` (there are a few other prefixes as well, see [1] for a full list), so that ARC doesn't automatically retain the return value.
2. Add `[return: Release ()]` to the api definition (this tells Xamarin.iOS what ARC is doing, and Xamarin.iOS will add an additional `release` call):

   ```
   [Static]
   [Export("newInstance")]
   [return: Release ()]
   WorksheetTableViewController NewInstance();
   ```

[1] http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#method-families

Comment: Thanks! This is quite crazy, I renamed the method to createInstance and now everything is awesome.